# google app engine with React and Node: Production setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-app-engine, ssl-certificate

I work with React.js and Node.js+Express to create a website. I use Google App Engine and Google Datastore for a database.

Everything works fine on my local machine:
React front end is able to access the API link served by Node. Node app is able to access the Datastore that runs on the cloud. 
On local machine I use Proxy to port 8080 of Node so that React would be able to access the API links.
from package.json file:
`"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"`
from React I make API calls using URLs: 
`axios.get('/api/XXX'`
I use HTTP server in Express.

When I deploy my code to Google App Engine, I am not sure what changes I need to do so that React app would be able to access Node API links.
Do I need a proxy in Prod? How to get SSL key and certificate from App Engine to put into Express? Should I switch right away to use HTTPS or can I still work with HTTP till I tune the rest of the building blocks to work together?

When I try to access links like:
`axios.get('https://my_custom_domain/api/XXX'`

then my React app is not able to access any of the API links. In Chrome console I see that React gets back 404 errors.

I use a custom domain and I see Google App Engine shows that my domain SSL security is "Google-managed, auto-renewing".
In Node I use HTTP server. I would like to switch to use HTTPS, but I don't understand how I can get the Private Key and the Certificate from App Engine console to put into the Express app.

Is there a way to get the Certificate and Private key from the App Engine Console? Or should I buy a new SSL certificate from a different party/company and use it in my Express app and upload it into App Engine ?

Here is my yaml file:
(server.js is my Node app)

`runtime: nodejs8
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: build
- url: /api/*
  script: server.js`

404 errors were about HTTPS. So I also switched from HTTP to HTTPS server. However, I have to initiate the HTTPS server without credentials, because Google App Engine doesn't allow me to see these creds.
here is what I do:
`var httpsServer = https.createServer(/*credentials,*/ app);`

However, I still have a 404 error:

> > >
> >     Failed to load https://www.XXXXX.XXX/api/v1/list: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://XXXXXXXXX.appspot.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
> >
> > > > >

I used the CORS library 
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

Yet, it still doesn't help and I get the cross origin error.

I also tried to introduce the following line in the App.Yaml:
`http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://xxxxxx.appspot.com`
Yet, when I try to deploy the code, `gcloud app deploy`
gcloud doesn't like this header, even though it is from its official documentation :) I think because API is considered a dynamic handler and hence I can't add http_headers to it.
the error of gcloud console is:
An error occurred while parsing file: [/xxxxxx/app.yaml]
Unexpected attribute "http_headers" for mapping type script.
  in "/Users/xxxxxx/app.yaml"

So I'm not sure how to fix the cross domain issue.

(I find it strange that there is no website that explains how to setup React + Node/Express in PROD for Google app engine. It is a pretty typical architecture )

Comment: 1) Where is this error coming from? `Failed to load https://www.XXXXX.XXX/api/v1/list: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://XXXXXXXXX.appspot.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.` If that's from the frontend, what do the server logs say? Anything more than just "404"? 2) What is the value under the `scripts.start` key path in `package.json`? 3) As noted,  `script: server.js` is not valid in `app.yaml`. Only `script: auto` is valid (and it's optional--so you can just remove that line).

Comment: The server side logs list the following problem:
>Static file referenced by handler not found: build/api/v1/list

So seems like the App Engine tries to direct the API call to the static folder "build" instead of the Node server. 

inside package.json I do use:
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",

Inside app.yaml I use:
runtime: nodejs8
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: build
- url: /.*
  script: auto

Comment: Ahhhh OK. I wasn't sure if the updated question reflected all the changes you made. That error log I think points to the issue. See my updated answer.

Comment: Well, now I get 500 errors. 
Sever Log: get to /api.xxx failed >The request failed because the instance could not start successfully
Client log: 500 error. cros-origin error.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://xxxx.appspot.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: OK, it seems like the request is now getting routed to the correct handler, at least. There are probably earlier error logs that provide more insight into why the instance isn't starting. Do you see any other error logs related to the instance attempting to start?

Comment: Seems like I found the other issue:
If I use httpServer.listen(8080);
Then App engine doesn't work.

I checked in App Engine docs in examples and they use:

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});

When I follow the examples, I get proper API responses.
Not sure why it makes a difference. 

I still have a CORS issue. I do get API response if my browser goes to the same sub-domain as the link from my API call. If not, I still get errors.

Comment: I managed to solve the CORS issue using the Node library Cors:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors.

still having the issue that when I go to my main domain without explicitly typing 'https' in front of it, then Chrome shows that the connection is not secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a custom domain with [Google-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl), you should be able to issue HTTPS requests to your production app automatically, without dealing with any SSL keys yourself. Given that you're seeing 404's in the logs, it looks like the requests are reaching your application alright, but not being routed to the desired handler code.

There are a few issues with your `app.yaml` configuration:

**1.** For the Node.js App Engine environment, the only valid value for the `script` key  of an entry under the `handlers` key of the `app.yaml` file is `auto` (see [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element)). Also, the `script` key is optional.

**2.** `- url: /api/*` should be `- url: /api/.*` See the section for the `url` key in the [same documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element).

**3.** Since App Engine attempts to match incoming requests against entries in `handlers` from first to last, and since entries with `static_dir` will match any request that *starts with* the value in `url` (see the [same documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element): "All URLs that begin with this prefix are handled by this handler, using the portion of the URL after the prefix as part of the file path"), a request to, for instance, `/api/v1/list` will match this handler:

```
- url: /
  static_dir: build
```

Thus, App Engine will try to serve a static file at `build/api/v1/list` in the app code, find no such file, and return a `404`. You should re-order your handlers so that requests starting with `/api` will find the API handler first.

Try this updated `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: nodejs8
handlers:
- url: /api/.*
  script: auto
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: build
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed your advice, but I encountered more issues. Note that I added details on the original question.

Comment: @jgaul, your updated `app.yaml` worked like a charm! Thanks. Note: I am building the backend separately, so I removed the first url handler (for now)

Comment: @pablo-az glad it helped you!

Answer (score -1):

"proxy" is for DEV enviroment so you should not use it in PROD.

Please try these steps;

**1.** Use GAE server url (we will define a server route in dispatch.yaml)

```
REACT_APP_API_ADDRESS = https://server-dot-xxx.appspot.com/api
```

**2.** CORS Front End settings (App.js). (***withCredentials is so important for session***)

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = [
  'https://xxx.appspot.com',
  'https://yourdomain.com',
  'https://www.yourdomain.com',
];
axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] =  
  true;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] =
  'DELETE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, OPTIONS';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] =
  'Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials , Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Set-Cookie, Cookie, Request, withCredentials';
```

**3.** CORS Back End settings (server.js) **(You must support this step with express session)**

```
const cors = require('cors');

const whitelist = [
  'https://xxx.appspot.com',
  'https://yourdomain.com',
  'https://www.yourdomain.com',
];

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('CORS ERROR'));
    }
  },
  allowedHeaders: [
    'Access-Control-Request-Method',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'Origin',
    'X-Requested-With',
    'Content-Type',
    'Accept',
    'Authorization',
    'X-HTTP-Method-Override',
    'Set-Cookie',
    'Cookie',
    'Request',
    'withCredentials',
  ],
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  origin: [
  'https://xxx.appspot.com',
  'https://yourdomain.com',
  'https://www.yourdomain.com',
  ],
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

**4.** Google Cloud > App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains

- ADD A CUSTOM DOMAIN;

  yourdomain.com
  [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com)
- Copy all of "Record Type" and "Data" lines and paste to your domain's DNS records

**5.** yaml for Client (React)

```
runtime: python39
service: client
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html

  - url: /(.*)
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(.*)
```

**6.** yaml for Server (Node)

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: server
entrypoint: node server.js
```

**7.** dispacth.yaml

```
dispatch:
  - url: 'server-dot-xxx.appspot.com/api/.*'
    service: server

  - url: 'xxx.appspot.com/*'
    service: client
```

I hope it helps!